# NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED in FireFox on mozRTCPeerConnection()

Tags: firefox, webrtc

I am using adapter.js in my webrtc 1-1 video call application. It works fine on Google Chrome and both peers see each other's video and can hear audio. However, when I run the same application on FireFox, I get the following error on console which comes from adapter.js.

```
NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED
```

This is the function from adapter.js which gives the above error on return statement:

```
var RTCPeerConnection = function(pcConfig, pcConstraints) {
  // .urls is not supported in FF yet.
  maybeFixConfiguration(pcConfig);
  return new mozRTCPeerConnection(pcConfig, pcConstraints);
};
```

This is what is inside pcConfig:

```
{"iceServers":[{"url":"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}]}
```

This is what is inside pcConstraints:

```
{"optional":[{"DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement":true},{"RtpDataChannels":true}],"mandatory":{}}
```

This is how the function `maybeFixConfiguration(pcConfig)` looks like:

```
function maybeFixConfiguration(pcConfig) {
  if (pcConfig == null) {
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < pcConfig.iceServers.length; i++) {
    if (pcConfig.iceServers[i].hasOwnProperty('urls')){
      pcConfig.iceServers[i]['url'] = pcConfig.iceServers[i]['urls'];
      delete pcConfig.iceServers[i]['urls'];
    }
  }
}
```

I don't understand what mistake I am doing here. Is something wrong with pcConfig and pcConstraints structure. I am using the latest FireFox I downloaded today.

Comment: Hi, I'm very interested in how you got that error. I'm on Firefox 38.0.1. and I'm not able to reproduce it with the inputs you mention. Would you mind posting a working code-snippet and what version you're on, or better yet [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=WebRTC) with that information? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake, it was in how we specify the iceServers.

Correction is :

```
{'iceServers': [
  createIceServer(isChrome
    ? 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
    : 'stun:23.21.150.121', null, null)
]}
```

Answer (score 3):

This may be outdated but it may be of some help.
I had the same `NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED` when creating the `new RTCPeerConnection(config)`.

My problem was that my `iceServers` array had an invalid `urls` part that was giving problems to Firefox, specifically i had 

`urls: 'turn:someUsername@ipAddress:port'`

I found out after some time that `someUsername@` was not acceptable to FF although it works on Chrome.

Removing the `username@` part of the string fixed the issue for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Update your browser. Fully qualified domain names in iceServer URLs [have been supported since Firefox 22 (circa March 2013)](https://bugzil.la/837919), and `adapter.js` does not generally cover browsers that old.

Also, note that `createIceServer` is no longer needed - and unavailable - in [the latest version of adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter/blob/master/adapter.js). There's still a polyfill in there for some changes in syntax, but it is handled transparently now, without needing to use this special function.