# RTCPeerConnection with RTCConfiguration breaks on Firefox

Tags: javascript, typescript, firefox, websocket, webrtc

Creating a new RTCPeerConnection with RTCConfiguration, like following code, works fine in Chrome 70 and Safari 12 but **breaks** in Firefox 63

```
const configuration: RTCConfiguration = {
  iceServers: [
    {
        urls: 'turn:user@myserver.com:3478',
        username: 'user',
        credential: 'mypwd'
    }
  ]
};

let rtcPeerConn: RTCPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
```

I have tried to `prefix` the `RTCPeerConnection` but didn't work neither, same error

```
// as above configuration
const PeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.msRTCPeerConnection;

let RTCPeerConn = new PeerConnection(configuration);
```

Then I have tried to add WebRTC [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtcHacks/adapter) but faced the same error

Finally I noticed that if I remove the `configuration` aka if I don't pass the configuration to the constructor, I don't face the error **but** is I try afterwards to set the configuration using the `setConfiguration` method I face an unknown function exception

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue is a duplicate and the answer to my question was given by @stefan-peshikj in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47127489/5404186

Turns out Chrome and Safari are more permissive than Firefox which doesn't accept an turn url with "username@"

Not accepted:

```
const configuration: RTCConfiguration = {
iceServers: [
  {
    urls: 'turn:user@myserver.com:3478', // <- here remove "user@"
    username: 'user',
    credential: 'mypwd'
  }
 ]
};
```

Accepted:

```
const configuration: RTCConfiguration = {
  iceServers: [
  {
    urls: 'turn:myserver.com:3478',
    username: 'user',
    credential: 'mypwd'
  }
  ]
};
```

This solves my issue. Thx @stefan-peshikj, not all heroes wear capes. If you would like to rewrite your answer here to get the karma point which you deserve, don't hesitate to do so